# How can I check a condition with a floating point?

Tags: assembly, mips

I want to create a loop that will make this program only accept values between 5 and 20. I've tried using blt but it says that $f0 is invalid

```
   li $v0,4            
   la $a0,improvement
   syscall

   li $v0,6             
   syscall
   l.s $f6, zero
   blt $f0,$f6, failure 



 failure:
   li $v0,4            
   la $a0,error
   syscall

   li $v0,6             
   syscall

mov.s $f4,$f0
```

So basically what happens is that the program reads a float value and I want it to check if it's less than 0 or greater than 20, if it is then go to the failure function and ask for a different value the once it is complete move the value in $f0 to $f4

Comment: FP comparisons are done in mips with with `c.xx.s fa, fb` where `xx` can be `eq`, `lt` or `le`. It sets a *condition bit* and `bclt label`and `bclf label` branch according to the status of the condition bit (t or f). Beware that equality comparison with FP  are likely to lead to unexpected behavior due to rounding errors.

Answer (score 0):

As Alain pointed out in a comment.  c.xx.s

```
unsigned int dofc ( float x, float y )
{
    if(x<y) return(1);
    return(0);
}

00000000 <dofc>:
   0:   460e603c    c.lt.s  $f12,$f14
   4:   00000000    nop
   8:   45010002    bc1t    14 <dofc+0x14>
   c:   24020001    li  $2,1
  10:   00001025    move    $2,$0
  14:   03e00008    jr  $31
  18:   00000000    nop
```

Comment: Note that this is for a real MIPS with branch-delay slots.  MARS simulates a MIPS without branch-delay slots by default, so you'd want to set `$v0` to `1` before the branch.